# regularity and blow up

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

i want to prove that if u satisfy:
$u_{t}-\Delta u=0 $ and $u=0$ in $\partial\Omega$ then $u \in C(]0,\infty[,H^{2}(\Omega))$, so i start by saying :$\|u\|_{H^{2}}\le c (\|u\|_{L^{2}}+\|D^{\alpha}u\|_{L^{2}})$ where$\lvert \alpha\rvert=2$
in addition we have that

$\|D^{\alpha}u\|_{L^{2}}\le  M \|\Delta u\|_{L^{2}}$

where$\lvert \alpha\rvert=2$

so finally i get

$\|u(t)-u(s)\|_{H^{2}} \le  C \|u(t)-u(s)\|_{L^{2}}+\|\Delta u(t)-\Delta u(s)\|_{L^{2}}$

so this is correct?
Thanks

Comment: If the domain is smooth enough, the inequality with $M$ is true (you can find it in Gilbarg-Trudinger, or even Evans I think). The rest of what you wrote is a tautology as far as I can tell. None of this involves the heat equation. If you want to show that solutions of the heat equation are in $C_tH^2_x$ using the inequality with $M$ (which is how I interpret the question), you might start by showing that $u_t \in L^2_{t,x}$, and so in $C_tL^2_x$ by energy estimates (as $u_t$ also solves the heat equation). You should be able to find similar arguments in standard parabolic texts.